# how to get the results of an answer and perform calculations on that result

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript code:

```
function suma(){
        var sum1 = document.getElementById("sum1");
        var sum2 = document.getElementById("sum2");
        var input = document.getElementById("resultado");
        resultado = (sum1.value * sum2.value);
        input.value= resultado;
    }
```

How do I perform a 1% calculation on the answer from the variable `resultado` and put the answer inside `premium`?

My code for doing that:

```
function percentage(){
        var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado").value;
        var input = document.getElementById("premium");
        var premium = (0.01*resultado.value);
        input.value = premium;

    }
```

the html codes

```
    <input type="number" class="form-control" required onblur="if(this.value 
     == ''){this.value='0'}" onKeyUp="suma();"  id="sum2"   name="Weight" 
    value="0" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" onblur="if(this.value == '') 
    {this.value='0'}"  onKeyUp="suma();" id="sum1"    name="variable" 
    value="3.25" readonly="readonly" />
    <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="shipping_subtotal" 
    id="resultado" value="0" />
    <input type="number" class="form-control"  id="insurance" 
    name="insurance" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'}"  
    name="variable" value="0.01" readonly="readonly" >
    <input type="number" class="form-control"  id="premium" name="premium" 
    value="0" onKeyUp "percentage();" >
```

Comment: Are you trying to find out what 1% of `resultada`'s value is or what `resultada`'s value is + 1%?

Comment: You are using `.value` twice in your code, which is probably why it is not working, see `resultado = document.getElementById("resultado").value` and `0.01*resultado.value`

Comment: @JosephWebber i am trying to find out what is 1% of resultado's value?

Comment: @JiFus i made changes and still it is not wroking.

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few minor errors in the code.  Don't worry though, they're easy to overlook in there.  One thing to keep in mind when developing is to keep your concerns separated, because your future self and other developers who work with your code will thank you.  What I mean by separation of concerns in this context is logic vs templating.  HTML is where templating belongs, and JavaScript is your logic.  When you write inline JavaScript, like `<input onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'}">`, it makes your JavaScript very difficult to follow and maintain.  In your JavaScript file, you can use `document.getElementById('demo').onblur = if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'};` instead, and now all your logic can be found in one place.  Personally, I prefer event listeners, because unlike onblur, you can assign multiple functions to the given event and you run less risk of overwriting any functionality that was written somewhere else.

Assuming `var el = document.getElementById('demo');`

METHOD 1:

```
el.onblur = if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'};

// This overwrites the onblur function from the line above
el.onblur = alert('hello');
```

METHOD 2:

```
el.addEventListener('blur', function() { if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'} });

// This does not overwrite the function above,
// instead, it just adds another function to the event.
el.addEventListener('blur', function() { alert('hello'); });
```

That aside, I believe your code will work with a few fixes to your errors.  To help you out, I wrote an alternative to your scripts above.  I'm not sure if I got everything the way you intended, though, so feel free to tweak it and make it your own.

```
var sum1 = document.getElementById("sum1");
var sum2 = document.getElementById("sum2");
var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
var premium = document.getElementById("premium");
var insurance = document.getElementById("insurance");

function calculateFields() {
  var suma = (sum1.value * sum2.value);
  resultado.value = suma;
  premium.value = (0.01 * suma);
}

var inputs = [sum1, sum2, resultado, premium, insurance];
inputs.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    this.value = this.value === '' ? 0 : this.value;
  });
  el.addEventListener('input', calculateFields);
});
```

Mess around with the code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zasxLhvr/29/).

Comment: it works perfectly. i want to improve on the code and perform further calculations on the result in premium,is increasing the elements in the array by creating variables  going to help?

Comment: Glad it helped!  That depends on what exactly you want to do, but I would probably add to `calculateFields()` if you need to do more calculations.  If you want to add more fields to show different results, then yeah there's nothing wrong with adding more elements to that array, it will always loop over all of the items no matter how short or long you make the array.